# LINQ anonymous type not giving the list I need

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, anonymous-types

I'm in the process of doing a LINQ query of an object call `Recipe` that need to be ordered by it's score. In the beginning, I have a `IEnumberable` of type `Recipe` (already filtered with the search criteria) called `selectedRecipies`

Then, with the help of my friend google, I have done this query using an anonymous type:

```
var finalQuery = ((from h in db.StarRatings
                       where selectedRecipies.Any(sr => sr.IDRecipe == h.IDRecipe)
                     group h by new { h.IDRecipe } into hh
                     select new
                     {
                         hh.Key.IDRecipe,
                         Score = hh.Sum(s => s.Score)
                     }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Score));
```

And I think it work... My problem is that for my view, I need it to be of type `Recipe` and `finalQuery` seems to be of type `IEnumerable<'a>` where `a` is the anonymous type...

How can I get a `List<>` of type Recipe without disturbing the OrderByDescending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new class `RecipeViewModel` (or `RecipeDto`) to capture the results:

```
select new RecipeViewModel
 {
     hh.Key.IDRecipe,
     Score = hh.Sum(s => s.Score)
 }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Score));
```

But you say

> I need it to be of type Recipe

which makes me suspect you need more (or all) data of `Recipe` to be presented. So you probably should restructure the query profoundly. And if so, you still can't use the `Recipe` class itself, because it has no `Score` property:

```
from r in db.Recipes
where // .....  (do your filtering here)
select new RecipeViewModel
  {
      Id = r.Id,
      // ... more recipe properties
      Score = r.StarRatings.Sum(rating => rating.Score)
  }
```

assuming that there is a navigation property Recipe.StarRatings. If not, you should use a `join` statement to include the ratings. (or introduce the navigation property).

Comment: You help me think of it. In fact, I needed the list of Recipe to create my list of RecipeViewModel... So just create my list of RecipeViewModel and did the order by right after... I feel so dumb! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating an anonymous type, you need to create a `Recipe`:

```
select new Recipe // Use constructor or object initiailizer here
                 {
                     ID = hh.Key.IDRecipe,
                     Score = hh.Sum(s => s.Score)
                 }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Score))
                 .ToList(); // To make your List<T>
```

Comment: But Recipe doesn't have a Score member since they already have the information in a list of voting

Comment: To be clearer, I mean that every Recipe has "0 to n" numbers of "Rating" made by users. Maybe the solution is to do an average of these all in one step and order by this but this is beyond my skills in linq...